# Read and Write 3D string array

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to write and then read a 3d array of strings to a file. The array is declared as `theatre[5, 5, 9]`. I have been looking but cant find anything I understand. It is basically just to switch between pages in a wp8 app.
How can I do this?
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Try walking the array and sending it to the Console first, then deal with the file part. Can you show what you've tried so far to walk the array?

Comment: I don't even know what walking the array is. I haven't tried anything because I don't even know where to start. I have only started learning programming this year, this is the first array ive used.

Comment: Are you sure that a 3D array is what you need? Start by stating what information exactly you are storing in that array (because I have a feeling you don't need a 3D space to store your data). You can post a short code snippet describing how you use the code. Generally, you can check the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class as it will allow you to serialize/deserialize any object into an XML file, but it would be much wiser to fix your domain model first.

Comment: It's a booking system for a theatre for a school project. Dimensions x and y are seat coordinates. The third coordinate I am using for various pieces of customer information such as name and phone number. I'm sure there's a better way to do it but we have to use arrays and I am not good at programming and am very committed to the 3d array at this point. It would be a lot of work to change it in a limited amount of time, even if something else is better. I basically have 3 days to get this working. So what would be the simplest way to save and recall this array? Regardless of how good it is?

Comment: Can you show us the type that is stored in the Array?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It seems you can simply use `BinaryFormatter.Serialize()` directly on your array as-is. It goes something like this:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

...    

// writing
FileStream fs = File.Open("...");
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(fs, theArray);

// reading
string[,,] theArray;
FileStream fs = File.Open("...");
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
theArray = (string[,,])bf.Deserialize(fs);
```

First solution (try this if BinaryFormatter fails):

You can translate between 3D and 1D as follows:

```
struct Vector {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    Vector(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}

Vector GetIndices3d(int i, Vector bounds)
{
    Vector indices = new Vector();

    int zSize = bounds.x * bounds.y;
    indices.x = (i % zSize) % bounds.x;
    indices.y = (i % zSize) / bounds.x;
    indices.z = i / zSize;

    return indices;
}

int GetIndex1d(Vector indices, Vector bounds)
{
    return (indices.z * (bounds.x * bounds.y)) +
        (indices.y * bounds.x) +
        indices.x;
}
```

Then it's just a matter of turning the 3D array to a 1D array and serializing it to a file. Do the opposite for reading.

```
string[] Get1dFrom3d(string[,,] data)
{
    Vector bounds = new Vector(data.GetLength(0), data.GetLength(1), data.GetLength(2));
    string[] result = new string[data.Length];

    Vector v;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
    {
        v = GetIndices3d(i, bounds);
        result[i] = data[v.x, v.y, v.z];
    }

    return result;
}

string[,,] Get3dFrom1d(string[] data, Vector bounds)
{
    string[,,] result = new string[bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.z];

    Vector v;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
    {
        v = GetIndices3d(i, bounds);
        result[v.x, v.y, v.z] = data[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Serializing the data to a file depends on the content of the data. You can choose a seperator character that does not appear in any of the data, and concatenate the strings using the separator.

If it's not possible to determine a distinct seperator character, you can choose one at your own convenience, and preprocess the strings such that the separator is escaped where it naturally appears in the data. This is usually done by inserting the seperator where it appears in the string such that it appears twise. Then handle this when reading the file (ie: pairs of separators = natural occurence of character data).

Another approach would be to turn everything into hexadecimal, and use some arbitrary separator. This will more or less double the file size.

Comment: I don't think that the OP wants to translate a 3D array into a 1D one. What he wants is to know how to deal with a 3D array but, for the information he want to store, don't need to use a 3D array; actually what would be the point? Example to understand this: store in a 3D array the following information: 1 -> (1, 2, 3, "asfasf"), 2 -> (2, 4, 5, "fdfdfdfd") -> this is what the OP wants to store and he thinks that needs a 3D array and want to know how to use it. How is your answer addressing all this?

Comment: Also I haven't ever used this kind of approach and I am not sure about the exact point (if you want the information in 1D why generating a 3D array in a first instance?); and there might be size-related issues: 1D 3-times bigger than the 3D one. Iterating through the 1D array will also be much more difficult... I don't get the point of this implementation (even in case that the OP would be looking for this).

Comment: OP asks how to read/write a 3d array of strings to/from a file. A file is a serial bytestream (1 dimension). My answer shows how to turn a 3d array into a 1d array, which can easily be serialized to a file. The 1D array is exactly the same size as the 3D equivalent (multiply the dimension bounds of the 3d array and you'll get the 1d size). No iteration is required except from serializing/deserializing which is simple.

Comment: With size I meant length (but you are right this is not an issue). But why not writing/reading by relying on the 3D array directly? Wouldn't this make the resulting file more "readable" too?. I am not sure about the exact advantage of taking something, converting it to something2, writing something2 to a file; and then, when reading the file, having to convert the something2 back to something. Mainly when you might have performed the writing in something anyway. In any case, I think that the OP is looking for an answer more on the lines of "how I store/retrieve this info, 3D is fine?".

Comment: There's no ubiquitous way of storing 3D data directly to a file. You have to somehow make a linear representation of the data. My answer is one example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment, it seems like you don't need a 3D array, even by relying on the quickest/dirtiest approach, you can/should use a 2D one. But you can avoid the second dimension by creating a custom class with the properties you want. Sample code:

```
seat[] theatre = new seat[5]; //5 seats

int count0 = -1;
do
{
    count0 = count0 + 1; //Seat number
    theatre[count0] = new seat();

    theatre[count0].X = 1; //X value for Seat count0
    theatre[count0].Y = 2; //Y value for Seat count0
    theatre[count0].Prop1 = "prop 1"; //Prop1 for Seat count0
    theatre[count0].Prop2 = "prop 2"; //Prop2 for Seat count0
    theatre[count0].Prop3 = "prop 3"; //Prop3 for Seat count0

} while (count0 < theatre.GetLength(0) - 1);
```

Where `seat` is defined by the following code:

```
class seat
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: seat[] theatre = new seat[5]; //6 seats

Your comment is wrong. That's only 5 seats.

Comment: @Pod Thanks. Coming now from the VB.NET questions and brought this bit with me (you know, in VB the number you put there when instantiating an array represents the upper bound, not the size) :)